# facebook login pop up shows Webpage not available

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the face javascript sdk with oAuth 2.0. I refereed this link for external website facebook login for my site https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/.

Now it shows *Web page not available* in my pop up and I checked with link above and there is also the same problem with the facebook domain. Is there a problem with facebook or am I doing something wrong? Please help me to figure this out.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#divFBButton').find('.fb_button').prop('disabled', true);

var FBAPPID = $('#ctl00_contentPlaceHolderRight_hdnFBAppID').val();
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    console.log('http://'+window.location.host+'/Dashboard/channel.html'+'channel URL');
   // console.log (window.location.host+'host checking');
    FB.init({
       appId: FBAPPID, cookie: true,
        status: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true
    });
};

(function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol
+ '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
} ());




<div id="fb-root">
        </div>
        <fb:login-button scope="manage_pages,offline_access,read_insights" size="large" style="opacity: .01 !important;
            width: 250px !important; line-height: 31px !important; margin-top: 0 !important;"
            onlogin="getPages()"> Sign In With Facebook Account </fb:login-button>
    </div>
```